# Reconcile Firefox slash handling and key codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage where users should be able to type anywhere and have their input tracked.  One problem is that the slash key, "/," in firefox is a shortcut for opening the search.  This is undesirable for me.  I have not found a way to trap the search functionality *and* still add the input to my tracking.  I add the input to the stack on `keypress`.

`keydown`...`preventDefault` works best in FireFox, but the problem is that in Chrome, `keypress` does not fire for some reason (not sure why `preventDefault` would stop that, but it does).  This would be okay if I could add the slash on my own to the input stack..but Firefox is already adding it because `keypress` is still triggered.  `stopPropagation` does not prevent `keypress` from triggering in FireFox either.  `$(document).keypress(e)` in the `keydown` method also does nothing.

Another issue I have is that "backspace" is supposed to remove from the stack, but I add to the stack with `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` and add the data to an `input type="text"` field that the user can see.  In Chrome this works perfectly, but in FireFox, it adds a character representing the backspace and then immediately removes it, preventing another character from being removed.  Having "backspace" and "f5," etc. characters in the input is also undesirable.  Is there a way to tell if the `fromCharCode` value is valid for a text field?  I think what's happening is that Chrome just does that automatically.

EDIT: This may help, but FireFox apparently triggers `keypress` before `keydown` (Chrome does the opposite) on my webpage.  This is unusual.

Comment: I didn't know the slash was used for search in FF, thanks!

Comment: @cambraca at least this question was good for something :P

Comment: It's not true that Firefox triggers `keypress` before `keydown`. Try the following test page, for example: http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html

Comment: @TimDown it may not be consistently true, but for my application it is for some reason.  I'll update the question to specify that it's at least *possible*, and related to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this with a bit of a kludge.  I have a `noslash` variable that triggers capturing the slash:

```
else if (e.which == '191' && !noslash) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $typing.val($typing.val() + '/');
}
```

As for the second part of the question, I simply reject any character in

```
[^-a-z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_+=\\|/'";:,<.>?\[\]{}]
```